# SQLAlchemy: Declarative ORM - build index using GIST and TSRANGE

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to build an index that essentially looks like this in sql:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS new_index ON schema.tablename USING gist (tsrange(start, "end"))
```

Where my declarative ORM model looks something like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Tablename(Mixins):

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.Index('index_name', postgresql_using="gist"),  # ????
        {'schema': 'schema'}
        )

    start = sa.Column(pg.TIMESTAMP, autoincrement=False, primary_key=True)
    end = sa.Column(pg.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
```

And later, I'd like to use `alembic` which should include a downgrade such as:

```
 op.drop_index('index', 'tablename', schema='schema')
```

Which effectively has the following SQL:

```
 DROP INDEX IF EXISTS schema.index
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you looking for [how to define a functional index](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#functional-indexes)?

Comment: I'm not sure I know enough to ask the right question.  Within the __table_args__, though, I have a `# ????`.  I think I need to massage that line to produce the sql I want.  I just do not know where to look or what the nomenclature is for sqlalchemy to find it.  Defining a function might be the right thing, but it's non-obvious from the documentation how to mix everything together (postgres GIST, TSRANGE, SQLAlchemy Index, SQA functional index, etc.)

Comment: You might run in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153301/flask-sqlalchemy-lower-case-index-skipping-functional-not-supported-by-sqlalc with alembic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's Index supports passing [SQL function expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#functional-indexes), given that the backend supports functional indexes:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class Tablename(Mixins):

    start = sa.Column(pg.TIMESTAMP, autoincrement=False, primary_key=True)
    end = sa.Column(pg.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.Index('index_name', sa.func.tsrange(start, end),
                 postgresql_using="gist"),
        {'schema': 'schema'}
        )
```

Note that if you move the `__table_args__` definition after the column attribute definitions, you can use them in your SQL function expression.

Comment: Awesome!  Will try that out in a bit.  Thanks!